# JQuery FAQ slider answers won't hide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, jquery-ui-slider

I'm using JQuery to make a vertical slider for FAQ Questions i.e. you click the question and the answer slides down. Everything is working except my answers are not hidden when the page loads. If you click a question so the answer slides up and then click that same question again to slide the answer down, only then do the rest of the answers slide up and hide. Can some one see what i'm doing wrong.

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
ul.qanda{
    color:#f5f5f5;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;padding:0}
.qanda li{
    border:1px solid #f5f5f5;
    margin:1em 0;padding:0}
.qanda .question{
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    font-size:1.3em;
    font-weight:300;
    padding:.75em 1.25em;
    position:relative}
.qanda .answer{
    border-top:1px dashed #f5f5f5;
    display:block;
    padding:.75em 1.25em}
.qanda a{
    color:#ccc}
.qanda .question{
    padding-left:1.5em}
.qanda .question:before{
    content:"+";
    font-weight:700;
    position:absolute;
    left:.5em}
.qanda .active:before{
    content:"-"}
</style>
```

JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".question").click(function(){
   var a = $(this).parent('li').find('.answer');
    if ( a.css('display') == 'none' ) {
        $('.question').removeClass('active');
        $('.answer').slideUp('fast');
        a.slideDown();
        $(this).addClass('active');
    } else {
            a.slideUp();
            $(this).removeClass('active')
    }
  });  });
 </script>
```

HTML

```
<ul class="qanda">
    <li>
            <strong class="question">Q: Question?</strong>
            <span class="answer">
                    A: Answer
            </span>
    </li>
    <li>
            <strong class="question">Q: Question?</strong>
            <span class="answer">
                    A: Answer
            </span>
    </li>
    <li>
            <strong class="question">Q: Question?</strong>
            <span class="answer">
                    A: Answer
            </span>
    </li>
    <li>
            <strong class="question">Q: Question?</strong>
            <span class="answer">
                    A: Answer
            </span>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/H8k8c/1/

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
   $('.answer').hide();
   $(".question").click(function () {
       var a = $(this).parent('li').find('.answer');
       if (a.css('display') == 'none') {
           $('.question').removeClass('active');
           $('.answer').slideUp('fast');
           a.slideDown();
           $(this).addClass('active');
       } else {
           a.slideUp();
           $(this).removeClass('active')
       }
   });
```

});

Comment: That was it! I've been staring at this for way to long lol. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just add an `$('.answer').hide();` to your code.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6Ye25/)**